# Lsyncd installing issue on 64bit

Tags: amazon-ec2, rsync

During the installation of Lsyncd 2.0.6  `./configure && make && make install` process I am receiving a not found error.

```
gcc: /usr/lib/liblua.a: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [lsyncd] Error 1
```

I use 64bit Amazon Ec2 Linux Ami and I checked `liblua.a` exists in `/usr/lib64/liblua.a`

What do I do to finish the install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lsyncd is available in EPEL (if you're using Amazon's linux, that's essentially RHEL):

```
$ yum info lsyncd
Loaded plugins: priorities, ps
Available Packages
Name        : lsyncd
Arch        : i686
Version     : 2.0.4
Release     : 1.el6.1
Size        : 60 k
Repo        : epel
Summary     : File change monitoring and synchronization daemon
URL         : http://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/
License     : GPLv2+
Description : Lsyncd watches a local directory trees event monitor interface (inotify).
            : It aggregates and combines events for a few seconds and then spawns one
            : (or more) process(es) to synchronize the changes. By default this is
            : rsync.
            :
            : Lsyncd is thus a light-weight live mirror solution that is comparatively
            : easy to install not requiring new file systems or block devices and does
            : not hamper local file system performance.
```

That's version 2.0.4.  You may want to stick with this version and let the repository folks manage patches, updates, etc.

If you really want to be on 2.0.6, you can grab the SRPM and rebuild it with the tar file for 2.0.6, but you should bear in mind that you'll be out of the repo-based updates for that package.  On the other hand, you'll have some sort of package management compared to what you're doing with `./configure ; make ; make install`, and the RPM SPEC file will better handle dependencies during build.

Comment: I guess I will go with version 2.0.4 for now. way easier!